# How to make Main Menu screen show up first (Libgdx)?

Tags: libgdx

I saw Mario Bros game on [Brent Aurelis tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZm85UZQLd2SXQzsF-a0-pPF6IWDDdrXt) on YouTube and basically he creates the game screen with implement screen, but I want to make my game start up with the main menu which I can't.

How can I do that?

Comment: I recommend looking at https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-flgt-home/ mainly at the menu control section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just change file name of *GameScreen* to  *MainMenuScreen* and set up your menu here ? This is just a question of naming, nothing forbids you to make your MainMenu in GameScreen and nothing forbids you to rename GameScreen class to MainMenuScreen.